# Problemas con un procedimiento que otorgue permisos en una BD en MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, permisos

Estoy haciendo un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL que me permita darle ciertos permisos al usuario que recibe  en los parámetros, sin embargo, no los asigna al usuario que le envío por parámetros al llamarlo, sino, crea un usuario con el mismo nombre del parámetro (en este caso 'usuario') y le asigna los permisos a dicho usuario. Cómo podría hacer para crear dicho procedimiento que me permita darle permisos a un usuario?
Acá el código del procedimiento:

```
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE tracker_system_db.administrador (IN usuario VARCHAR(20))
    BEGIN
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON tracker_system_db.* TO usuario;
    flush PRIVILEGES;
    END;
    //
```

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código te crea un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL para asignar todos los privilegios a un usuario, el nombre del usuario debes pasarlo como parametro y el procedimiento primero: determina si el el usuario existe y luego le asigna los privilegios.

Prueba y marca la respuesta si satisface tu requerimiento.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `set_admin`(
     IN `p_usuario` VARCHAR(50))
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

    DECLARE existe boolean DEFAULT FALSE;

    SELECT
      COUNT(USER) INTO existe
    FROM `mysql`.`USER`
    WHERE `mysql`.`USER`.`USER` = `p_usuario`;

    IF NOT existe THEN
        SELECT 'Este usuario no existe';
    ELSE
        SET @`sql` := CONCAT('GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON tracker_system_db.* TO ', `p_usuario`);
        PREPARE statement FROM @`sql`;
        EXECUTE statement;                   -- Ejecutar query.
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;        -- Eliminar query alojado en memoria.
        FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

    END IF;

END
```